# Area element (First fundamental form) in Cartesian and Cylindrical coordinate system

Tags: differential-geometry

I realized it maybe a dumb question, but anyway...

I have a surface $S$ parameterized by $(t,s)$ and expressed Cartesian coordinated $\textbf x (t,s)= (x(t,s),y(t,s),z(t,s))$, also the same surface parameterized by $(t',s')$ in Cylindrical coordinates $\textbf x(t',s')=(r(t',s'), \theta(t',s'),z(t',s'))$. My question is how to convert first fundamental form between each other?

Example: Helicoid

In Cartesian: $\textbf x(u,v)=(ucosv,usinv,cv)$, $E=1,G=c^2+u^2, F=0, dA=\left\lVert \frac{\partial \textbf x}{\partial u}\wedge \frac{\partial \textbf x}{\partial v}\right\lVert dudv=\sqrt{EG-F^2}du\wedge dv=\sqrt{c^2+u^2}du\wedge dv$

In Cylindrical: $\textbf r(r,\theta)=(r,\theta,c\theta)$, $E=1,G=c^2+1, F=0, dA=\sqrt{EG-F^2}dr\wedge d\theta=\sqrt{c^2+1}dr\wedge d\theta$

I know I'am missing $dA(u,v)=d\textbf r(r,\theta)\frac{(r,\theta)}{(u,v)}$, but it seems to me $r=u,\theta=v$, so I come the conclusion: $d A(u,v) \neq dA(r,\theta)$ under different coordinate system, even the parameterization is the same $r=u,\theta=v$. I know it is wrong... can you help me out?

Edit-----
I think I found the issue. In Cylindrical, $\textbf r_r=\textbf e_r$ and $\textbf r_\theta=-\theta\textbf e_r +r\textbf e_\theta + c\textbf e_z$, $E=<\textbf r_r, \textbf r_r> = 1$ and $G=<\textbf r_\theta,\textbf r_\theta>=\theta^2+r^2+c^2$, $F=<\textbf r_r,\textbf r_\theta>-\theta$,

then $dA=\sqrt{EG-F^2}dr\wedge d\theta=\sqrt{c^2+r^2}dr\wedge d\theta$
or in general $dA=\left\lVert \frac{\partial \textbf r}{\partial r}\wedge \frac{\partial \textbf r}{\partial \theta}\right\lVert dr\wedge d\theta=\begin{vmatrix}
E & F\\
F & G
\end{vmatrix}dr\wedge d\theta=\left\lvert g_{ij}\right\lvert dr\wedge d\theta$ and $r=u$.

It agrees the results in Cartesian. The interesting part is $F(r,\theta,z) \neq 0$ The tangential line in cylindrical coordinates are not orthogonal, means the parametrization coordinates are not orthogonal.

Comment: First, using $S$ for the parametrization and then in the expression $dS$ is wrong; the element of surface area is not the derivative of the parametrization. Second, your parametrization of the helicoid in cylindrical coordinates is wrong; you still need to give $x,y,z$ coordinates as functions of $r,\theta$ if you're trying to compute surface area in $\Bbb R^3$. If you do it correctly, you won't have the contradiction.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thanks for your reply. I am afraid I am still very confused about the two bullets you pointed out.

Comment: @TedShifrin. Not sure why "the element of surface area is not the derivative of the parametrization"? My understanding ‖‖∂∂∧∂∂‖‖ is the element area. Maybe I have same fundamentally wrong about the concept? Second issue is something I struggled alot. I do know if give $x(r,\theta), y(r,\theta), z(r,\theta)$ I can have correct results. But it is done in cartesian. I would like to do it purely in cylindrical.Thanks in advance

Comment: First, if $f(u,v)$ is a function, then $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}dv$, and this has absolutely nothing to do with the element of surface area. Second, using $(r,\theta,z)$ as your coordinates doesn't give the *Euclidean* surface area or volume; why do you expect to get the same answer? Try the disk $z=0$, $0\le r\le a$, $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$. You get area $2\pi a$, which is certainly not $\pi a^2$. The first fundamental form captures the induced metric, which is no longer coming from the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thanks for the first part. I abused the notation. I think I kinda understand your second comment. I realized I had similar issue in undergraduate, but I let it and it hurts back now. I am still confused. Because same surface living in Cartesian $x, y, z$ or Cylindrical $r,\theta,z$ should have the same area. What I mean is take volume of cylinder for example, in $(r,\theta,z)$, $\iiint_V r \,dr\,d\theta,dz $ but in $(x,y,z)$, $\iiint_V f(x,y,z) \,dx\,dy,dz $ can also be done (although it is complicated...). My question is: is there similar way to do surface?

Comment: Precisely, you need to work with the appropriate orthonormal coframe in polar/cylindrical coordinates, which is $dr,r\,d\theta,dz$. This requires some thought.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I have figured it out. The interesting part is is (,,)≠0. Can I make the following statement:The tangential line in cylindrical coordinates are not orthogonal, means the parametrization coordinates are not orthogonal.

Comment: No, the coordinates *are* orthogonal, but, as I indicated, you do not have an ortho*normal* set-up. Think about polar coordinates. Why is $dA = \color{red}{r}\,dr\wedge d\theta$? Your $F$ was nonzero for the helicoid, yes, but in most parametrizations of *surfaces* we don't have $F=0$. That is *not* the issue.